# Нужно ли тире

Tags: тире

Зебра и радуга чем-то похожи, Зебра в полосочку, радуга тоже. 
Нужно ли тире после слов "Зебра" и "тоже"?

Answer (score 3):

Тире факультативно, а вот вместо запятой лучше поставить двоеточие, потому что вторая часть бессоюзного сложного поясняет, раскрывает смысл первой:

Зебра и радуга чем-то похожи(чем именно?):

Зебра в полосочку, радуга тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно, но можно поставить.

Answer (score 1):

Постановка тире в неполных предложениях факультативна и проверяется интонацией.

В данном случае тире лучше не ставить, в этом случае дополнительные паузы отсутствуют, тоническое ударение падает на слова "в полосочку", "тоже", что лучше соответствует стихотворному ритму.